# fatal: ambiguous argument when using git in my pipelines

Tags: git, bitbucket, pipeline

I am executing the following command :

`npm run affected:build:dev -- --base="$(git rev-parse origin/develop^1)"`

with expected output to be the hash of the previous commit in develop
ex once run

`nx affected:build --configuration=develop "--base=09a1a7cf53c00a2010d907574710c71674acdf80"`

this command works fine when I run on the terminal of my computer, but when running inside my bitbucket pipeline, it fails with the following error :

```
+ npm run affected:build:dev -- --base="$(git rev-parse origin/develop^1)"
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/develop^1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
> anylogi-frontend@1.1.6 affected:build:dev
> nx affected:build --configuration=develop "--base=origin/develop^1"
fatal: Not a valid object name origin/develop^1
fatal: No such ref: 'origin/develop^1'
nx affected:build
```

I don't understand the cause, my pipeline is running the same versions as my local.
`git version 2.25.1`
`node v16.13.0`
`npm 8.1.0`

what is the syntax that git is expecting ?

Comment: Your bitbucket pipeline is probably using a single-branch (and probably shallow as well) clone. Make it not do that, and you'll have the commits and names you want. (How, precisely, you do that is a Bitbucket pipelines question, not a Git one; I don't have that answer for you since I haven't used Bitbucket pipelines myself.)

Comment: yes that was the problem, it works only if I use this in the branch I try to get the hash from. Thank you ! it is indeed not a git problem but a bitbucket configuration one.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the '`^`' in `develop^1` is not correctly interpreted by the shell, try instead:

```
git rev-parse origin/develop~1
```

In your case, the first parent (`^1`) should be the same as the first generation ancestor of the named commit object (`~1`).

Try also a `git log origin/develop` in your pipeline, just to confirm that, in the context of said pipeline execution, there is indeed a history fetched and associated with `origin/develop`.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
I just ran `git log origin/develop` and it trigger `unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` I will try to go from here.

Comment: @Bobby Exactly: a fetch seems missing.